# Squares modulo an odd prime

Tags: number-theory

In Theorem 2.6 of [Examples Of Mordell's Equation](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf), Conrad writes:

> ..., so $y^{2} \equiv -18 \,\mathrm{mod}\,p$. Hence $-18 \equiv \square\,\mathrm{mod}\,p$, so $-2 \equiv \square\,\mathrm{mod}\,p$.

Note that $p$ is an odd prime. Why does the second implication hold? If $-18$ is some quadratic residue, then why does it follow that $-2$ is also the quadratic residue?

Comment: Because $9$ is a square mod.  any $p$…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Legendre symbol we have
$$
1=\left(\frac{-18}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-3^2\cdot 2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right).
$$
So if $-18$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then also $-2$.